# AJAX to update different ids on a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My app have a relation of Many passengers to One flight. And that's it.

I have a "flight show view", which show all passengers assigned to that flight and it works nicely.

```
def show
 @passengers = @flight.passengers.order('is_checked ASC, is_boarded ASC, name ASC')
end
```

But my problem is now I want to add a partial to make ajax calls that updates passengers like a form (with remote: true) to update a single paramenter of a passenger based on a text field. For example:

In my show view I have a text_field which if I write "Passenger name 1", I want to update the column of "is_boarded" of that passenger to true when clicked to submit.

The problem I'm facing is that when I try to do this I cant select that ID of the passenger and send it to the update of passengers controller (I would make a conditional to update only that field at the update passengers method to check by referer, maybe), since I'm at flights controller.

My idea was to use a form_tag with remote: true to an action which I would change by jQuery based on the text written at the textbox, but even forcing a direct action to specific ID (55 in this case) I cant make this:

```
<%= form_tag('/passengers/55/edit', method: :post, remote: true) do %>

    <%= text_field_tag 'name' %>

    <%= submit_tag %>

<% end %>
```

Tried to use "update" instead of "edit" also, but didn't worked.

But what I see at the console is:

```
Started POST "/passengers/55/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-25 22:55:00 -0300
Processing by PassengersController#index as JS
```

Maybe should I use respond_to at passengers#index to fix this? If so, how?

If this is too much work maybe help me to search for the right things? Thank you for your time!

Comment: wanna post your controller code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you've got multiple steps to the problem here, but none of them should be too hard to implement;
-Selecting individual passengers from the @passengers instance variable.
-Creating a new route for this particular update
-Updating that single passenger via Ajax from the show page

First up, rather than involving any kind of text recognition or parsing, and to avoid human error etc. Rather than type a name, why don't you use a select box? Something like;

```
<%= select_tag :passenger_id, options_for_select(@passengers.all.map {|pass| [pass.name, pass.id]}), {:include_blank => 'Select A Passenger'} %>
```

If you put that in place of the text field it will create a dropdown box linking names to ID's.

Next, Since this is just a quick boolean switch, but with a dynamic aspect, I'd recommend creating a new Restful Patch route and controller action for it ([Rails Routing](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) 2.10 Adding More RESTful Actions);

```
//routes.rb 

resources :passengers do
    member do
        patch "onboard"
        put "onboard"
    end
end
```

And in your Controller use the [toggle](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-toggle-21) method, it toggles the attribute (it'll go back to false if you hit it twice) and save it;

```
//passenger_controller.rb
def onboard
    respond_to do |format|
        @passenger = Passenger.find(params[:id])
        @passenger.toggle!(:onboard)
        format.html {}
        format.json {}
    end
end
```

I'm just assuming that you don't want to load a new page after this (ie. ongoing boarding process) so the respond_to block ends with empty headers.

What this all boils down to is that you now have a secondary update route('edit' and 'onboard') that you can call from a form. If you run your `rails routes` command you'll see it there. Now plop that into your html and you should be good.

```
<%= form_tag(onboard_passenger_path, method: :post, remote: true) do %>

   <%= select_tag :passenger_id, options_for_select(@passengers.all.map {|pass| [pass.name, pass.id]}), {:include_blank => 'Select A Passenger'} %>

    <%= submit_tag %>

<% end %>
```

Codes untested, might be a kink or two to iron out but should be alright.

Comment: It helper a lot! That patch/put is new to me. Btw, it is still not working, sadly. It doesn't fire the "onboard" method at the passengers controller. Neither a "puts" to test the onboard method isn't fired when I click the submit button. Maybe it's because I'm in Flights_Show view (at Flights controller) and trying to update a Passenger model? Anyway, thanks for your help, it surely helped me going ahead. Marked as answer

Comment: Damn dude, I got to fix it. Thank you so much for your help. I just needed to change two things. One was I had a route at the very bottom to route wrong URLs to a specific page (this route was getting in the way and not going to my controller's method). The other one was I just changed the Passenger.find(params[:id]) to Passenger.find(params[:passenger_id]), which is what the form is sending. TY!